# Transparencia de un botón Android

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, quisiera saber, ¿Cómo hago parcialmente transparente mi botón sin perder la opacidad del texto que lleva?

Intenté hacerlo así:

```
android:alpha="0.1"
```

Pero, el texto ni se ve. Yo necesito que el botón sea casi transparente pero que el texto se vea bien claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el color transparente definido en el SDK, este color lo defines como fondo en tu botón:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    ...
    ...
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

programaticamente lo puedes realizar de esta forma, también definiendo el color transparente:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

---

Si no deseas un color completamente transparente puedes cambiar el "alpha" que son los 2 primeros digitos del color, son valores hexadecimales cuyos valores van desde 0 a 9 y desde A a F, puedes cambiar de transparente a completamente opaco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo si deseas usar el color semitransparente `#22000000`) lo puedes definir de esta forma a tu Vista:

```
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#22000000"));
```

Comment: Si, pero esto hace que se vea transparente al 100%. Y yo quiero que se vea un poco

Comment: Hola amigo @FranqoBalsamo agregue como lograr lo que deseas, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

En el metodo onCreate de tu Activity:

Llama al boton y cambia el alpha al background ,tocara el background y no el texto.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.getBackground().setAlpha(0.1 * 255);
```

Comment: Pues, esta no me deja porque el valor de alfa debe ser `int`

Comment: Si es int entonces es de 0 a 255, para convertir es simplemente multiplicar 0.1 * 255